# Как удалить из адресной строки определенный параметр?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?param=myparam&test=testname

есть функции для извлечения всех параметров, но как удалить определенный?

может быть есть готовая функция чтобы не пользоваться регулярками? в данном случае мне нужно удалить параметр `myparam`, который может стоять в любой части не только первым
 На выходе строка должна иметь вид:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?test=testname

Comment: `var hash = {}; url.split('?')[1].split('&').foreach((e)=>{hash[e.split('=')[0]]=e.split('=')[1]})` Ну и потом удаляем из хеша, и собраем обратно. :-)

Comment: вам нужно в адресной строке браузера удалить, или просто в переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function removeParam(key, sourceURL) {
  var splitUrl = sourceURL.split('?'),
    rtn = splitUrl[0],
    param,
    params_arr = [],
    queryString = (sourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? splitUrl[1] : '';
  if (queryString !== '') {
    params_arr = queryString.split('&');
    for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      param = params_arr[i].split('=')[0];
      if (param === key) {
        params_arr.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    rtn = rtn + '?' + params_arr.join('&');
  }
  return rtn;
}

var url = "http://someUrl.ru?param1=123&param2=234&param3=435";

var url1 = removeParam("param1", url);
var url2 = removeParam("param2", url);
var url3 = removeParam("param3", url);

console.log(url);
console.log(url1);
console.log(url2);
console.log(url3);

var testUrl = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?param=myparam&test=testname';
var urlTest = removeParam("param", testUrl);
console.log(urlTest);
```

Comment: а как вставить новый урл в адресную строку, но не перезагружать страницу? (просто вставить)

Comment: window.history.pushState({}, document.title, `новый url` );

Comment: `sourceURL.split('?')` вызываете несколько раз в функции, лучше вынести наверх и вызвать один раз, а далее уже использовать результат, а так получаются лишние вызовы

Comment: `pushState` вставляет в историю как новый объект истории, то есть если нажать назад, то он перейдёт не первый адрес, а первый отправит обратно на новый, таким образом работа истории будет нарушена, а `replaceState` заменяет текущий без вставки нового.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, пожалуй вы правы, использование replaceState будет лучше. Спасибо за улучшение ответа.

Comment: я ещё второй комментарий, выше, написал

Answer (score 2):

с ограниченной поддержкой браузеров, можно так

```js
var link = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?param=myparam&test=testname';

var url = new URL(link);
url.searchParams.delete('test');

console.log(url);
```

Comment: вообщем-то неплохая поддержка на мой взгляд - https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams , спасибо за ответ, буду знать